# Configurable swatches 1.9.2 max attributes

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.2.0, swatches, color-swatches

I am using configurable swatches that was included with the new version of Magento...It works great, until I reach what seems to be the max number of allowed swatch-ed attributes. How would I go about changing the max number? Sounds like maybe an array is initialized and I'm reaching the bounds of it...?

Comment: In reference to the max, you are referring to the `Product Attributes to Show as Swatches in Product Detail` System > Configuration > Configurable Swatches > General Settings option?

Comment: the maximum number that you can possibly configure there is limited by the size of the value column in core_config_data (64kb). The question needs more information: what seems to be the maximum number? what happens when you reach it?